# Magento 2 Extension Packaging: How to include sample CSV file in var directory

Tags: magento2, extensions, packaging

Recently I developed my first magento 2 extension. In this extension I am going to give admin an option to import a CSV. For that I have given a sample CSV to download.

In My development server its inside var directory. And I am able to access.

```
$sample_file = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList')->getPath('var') . '/my_sample.csv';
```

I was wondering how to include this sample file while packaging the extension and upload to magento marketplace.

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: you can create the sample with php code?